# How to add a table in django form?

Tags: django-forms

I am creating a Django form which requires several details to be filled by user (number of pieces and dimensions) so I was thinking to include a table in the form.This is only a info collector and would not go to database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use {{form.as_table}} template tag built in django.
{{form.as_table}} returns only <\tr>...</tr>. You would have to explicitly put the  wrapper around.

For more visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/